# Growing text-decoration:underline with multiline text

Tags: css, text-decorations

How can i make growing text-decoration:underline like here
http://www.codeit.co/code/93l but for multiline text (more than one  row).

Or how can i do it with jquery?

Comment: It's impossible to do `css` only.

Comment: ок- how do it with jquery?